# salesforce integration with google data api

Tags: eclipse, subversion

I am trying to do salesforce integration with google data api. Google data api has some code that is in svn. So I have downloaded eclipse, subclipse 1.6(we also tried with 1.10 as well) and all subclipse related downloads. 
and when we use the instructions given in the bottom link to download svn url(http://apex-google-data.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) it is giving the following error.[image: error in eclipse]

i have disable javahl as well and i have also installed svnkit client adapter and svnkit library.
on a different note, clicking the svn reposity link also it shows that svn/trunk path not found.  But the documentation says it should work. i am confused. can anybody give some suggestion over this. Please let me know if i miss anything.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Data_APIs_Toolkit_Setup#Checking_Out_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_Google_Data_APIs

Answer (score 0):

I believe google has deprecated that link. you could try https://github.com/shunjikonishi/apex-google-api